# How to show data in datatables using php prepared statement using mysqli?

Tags: php, json, mysqli, datatables, prepared-statement

> This code is working fine when i use php mysqli to show result in table(using datatables)

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
if (!$result) {
    die("Database query failed.");
}
$res = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    array_push($res, $row);
}
echo json_encode($res);

{
data: "distributor_name"
}, {
data: "order_date"
}, {
data: "product_name"
}, {
data: "nsp"
}, {
data: "region"
}, {
data: "current-sales"
}, {
data: "closing-balance"
}, {
data: "CBTotal"
},{
data: "CSTotal"
},{
data: "pro_ID"
}
```

> But i want to use php prepared statement, what is the error in this code? How to pass php variables there?

```
$stmt->bind_result($distributor_name, $order_date, $product_name, $nsp, $region, $pro_ID, $current_sales, $closing_balance);
 $json = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    array_push($json, $row);
}
echo json_encode($json);
    $stmt -> close();
```

Comment: why do you have to use prepared statement?

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `distributor_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

with data:

```
id   distributor_name    product_name
1    distributor1        product2
2    distributor2        product3
3    distributor1        product4
```

Let's say you want to get products for `distributor1`. You do something like this:

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "password", "test");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$distributor = "distributor1";

/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `distributor_name` = ?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $distributor);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $distributorName, $product);

    /* fetch values */
    $results = [];
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $results[] = [$id, $distributorName, $product];
    }

    echo json_encode($results);

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
```

**UPDATE**

The error is in this code:

```
   while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
       array_push($json, $row);
   }
```

`$stmt->fetch()` returns `true`, `false` or `null` , your json will probably hold only `true` values.

Comment: Thanks alot i did the same but my question is should i use those variables like this? {
data: "$distributor_name"
}, {
data: "$order_date"
},

Comment: Please clarify what exactly are you trying to achieve? Not sure I understand you.